# call AngularJS service method based on the response from bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a bootstrap popover which has 2 buttons Yes or No. Based on the response from the user i need to call AngularJS service function. How do i do that??

Popover is created only if it meets a certain criteria (like existence of duplicate records)

HTML code looks something like below, but currently doesn't have 2 buttons & still need to work on it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (DuplicateRecord) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    }
});
```

```html
<button href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header"
       data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-trigger="click"
       data-html="false" data-placement="left">
  Toggle popover
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixin concepts (or maybe I'm not getting your question), you can have a popover but the `data-trigger="click"` makes showing the popover on the click event and you wanna use that event to call the service method. Change the popover trigger to `hover` and then use the `click` event to call your service. Something like this just as an idea, the snippet is not tested.

```
<button 
   type="button"
   data-toggle="popover" 
   title="Popover Header"
   data-content="Some content inside the popover" 
   data-trigger="hover"
   data-html="false" 
   data-placement="left"
   ng-click="$ctrl.callSomeMethod()"
>
    Toggle popover
</button>
```

You can take a look to [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) lib which has a directives for the Bootstrap's components equivalents.

Comment: No, data-trigger="Click" just creates a popover & popover has 2 different buttons(yes or no). If the users clicks button Yes then we should be calling angular service.

Comment: Are you saying that you wanna trigger click events for buttons inside the popover?

Comment: Yes, i want to trigger click events for buttons inside the popover